# Angularjs ui for bootstrap

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

i'm using the Angularjs ui for bootstrap library. In particular im,  wanting to customise the  the  behaviour of the "collapse" directive. Currently, if i have more than one collapsable section on a page itcollapses them all at the same time. I would like to seperate them out so i can know which element triggered the event. And collapse only that section. Ive tried a few different ways including adding the $event expression inside ng-click but its coming back undefined.

I was hoping that someone could help me fix this code please?

```
.directive("collapse", ["$transition", function (e, $event) { var t = function (e, t, n) { t.removeClass("collapse"), t.css({height: n}), t[0].   offsetWidth, t.addClass("collapse") };

return{link: function (n, a, i) { var r, o = !0; n.$watch(function () { return a[0].scrollHeight }, function () { 0 !== a[0].scrollHeight && (r || (o ? t(n, a, a[0].scrollHeight + "px") : t(n, a, "auto"))) }), n.$watch(i.collapse, function (e) { console.log(r); e ? u() : c() //removed for testing }); var l, s = function (t) { return l && l.cancel(), l = e(a, t), l.then(function () { l = void 0 }, function () { l = void 0 }), l }, c = function () {

o ? (o = !1, r || t(n, a, "auto")) : s({height: a[0].scrollHeight + "px"}).then(function () { r || t(n, a, "auto") }), r = !1 }, u = function () { r = !0, o ? (o = !1, t(n, a, 0)) : (t(n, a, a[0].scrollHeight + "px"), s({height: "0"})) } }} }])
```

Comment: shouldn't all collapse if you set different variables for each one to define collapse state. Create a demo in plunker or jsfiddle.net that replicates your issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is likely that you have used the same scope variable for `collapse` for each of the inidividual instances. This would wire them all together.

As you can see from this demo, they play well together when the variables are different

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/KLHNiie1xELJfVPPxYtE?p=preview)**</kbd>